# MongoDB Query Failing

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have saved the below query as med.js

```
var cust = db.Collection.find({"email":null});
var count = 0;
print("total entries: ",cust.length(),"  ",cust.hasNext());
while(cust.hasNext()){
nextCust = cust.next();
db.Collection.update({_id:nextCust._id},{$set : {"email":""}});
count++;
}
print("total updated: ",count);
```

When I am executing this Query as
***mongo dbName --port 13017 ~/Documents/med.js***

output is
**total entries:  491502    false

total updated:  0**

How come total entries are showing as 491502 but hasNext() is false. its not going in the while loop

Comment: find() returns a cursor, and cursor doesn't have method length https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/.  Are you sure that the collection name is right?

Comment: I am writing Collection only for reference but the actual collection name is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different methods you can use in this context.

- **cursor.count()**   Modifies the cursor to return the number of documents
  in the result set rather than the documents themselves.
- **cursor.itcount()**     Computes the total number of documents in the
  cursor client-side by fetching and iterating the result set.
- **cursor.size()**    Returns a count of the documents in the cursor after
  applying skip() and limit() methods.

cursor.length is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 4):

The `cursor.length()` function exhausts the cursor by converting it into an array. Check the function code.

```
>cur.length
function (){
    return this.toArray().length;
}
```

Hence you're getting `false`.

To get the count without exhausting the cursor, use `cursor.count()`